# Is there any restriction on size of extent report that can be generated?

Tags: selenium-extent-report

We have a requirement where image needs to be added after every step for test cases(Selenium+ Java+ TestNG + Extent Reports). 
Is there any restriction on the size of the extent report that can be generated?

Extent version used: 2.41.2

We were able to execute 109 test cases and get extent report with file size of 178 MB. After that test cases are executed, but extent report is not generated. There is no error.

200 test cases need to be executed and extent report with images should be generated.

Comment: May be you can flush the report after every test.